# Value given by NIntegrate is double of Integrate function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, numerical-value

I am performing a calculation where the result of NIntegrate and Integrate is different. They differ by factor of 2. Can someone tell what is the reason and how to make the NIntegrate value right?,

```
g[\[CapitalOmega]0_, \[Omega]_] := Assuming[(\[CapitalOmega]0*10^4* Cos[\[Omega]*t])^2  > (2*\[Omega]*
  Sin[\[Omega]*t])^2, NIntegrate[Sqrt[(\[CapitalOmega]0*10^4* Cos[\[Omega]*t])^2  - (2*\[Omega]*
    Sin[\[Omega]*t])^2], {t, 0, 2*Pi/\[Omega]}]]
```

Here is the output:
[image: For NIntegrate]
Another one,
[image: For Integrate]
Any help?
System Detail: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and Mathematica 13.2

Comment: Try `g[2, 2*Pi/10]`.  It's better to use exact numbers with exact solvers like `Integrate`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is that the expression for the indefinite integral is valid for the first half-period only

```
f[t_] = Integrate[Sqrt[(\[CapitalOmega]0*10^4*Cos[\[Omega]*t])^2 - 
(2*\[Omega]*  Sin[\[Omega]*t])^2], t]

Out=(10000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2 Sqrt[
   25000000 - \[Omega]^2/\[CapitalOmega]0^2 + (25000000 + \[Omega]^2/\
\[CapitalOmega]0^2) Cos[2 t \[Omega]]] EllipticE[t \[Omega],  1 + \[Omega]^2/(
     25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2)])/(\[Omega] Sqrt[-\[Omega]^2 + 
    25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2 + (\[Omega]^2 + 
       25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2) Cos[2 t \[Omega]]])
```

The elliptic integral

```
EllipticE[t \[Omega],  1 + \[Omega]^2/( 25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2)]
```

generally is the function descibing time as a function of the angle of a rotating pendulum and therefore like arcsin etc has a finite interval of definition on the real line.

```
Plot[{h[t], f[t]} /. {\[CapitalOmega]0 -> 2, \[Omega] -> 0.2 \[Pi]}, {t, 0, 
   2*Pi/\[Omega]} /. {\[CapitalOmega]0 -> 2, \[Omega] -> 0.2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The solution is, to determine the period and to integrate over the first period only.

Comment: Can you tell me what is h[t] in the plot and i want to plot a graph of the integration value vs Omega_0 is it possible to do?, I have done it but using Integrate , makes the code very long time to run.

Comment: The periodic function is the given integrand, the truncated function is its integral. Both plotted by their algebraic expressions with the given values of the constants

Comment: Why do you think the Newton-Leibniz formula is applied? See the @MichaelE2 's comment to the question. `Integrate[
 Sqrt[(\[CapitalOmega]0*10^4*Cos[\[Omega]*t])^2 - (2*\[Omega]*
      Sin[\[Omega]*t])^2], {t, 0, x}, 
 Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= 10]` performs a conditional expression

Comment: `(10000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2 Sqrt[
 25000000 - \[Omega]^2/\[CapitalOmega]0^2 + (25000000 + \[Omega]^2/\
\[CapitalOmega]0^2) Cos[2 x \[Omega]]]
  EllipticE[x \[Omega], 
  1 + \[Omega]^2/(
   25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2)])/(\[Omega] Sqrt[-\[Omega]^2 + 
  25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2 + (\[Omega]^2 + 
     25000000 \[CapitalOmega]0^2) Cos[2 x \[Omega]]])`.